# Getting state after HTML5 history.pushState(...)

Tags: html, history

It seems after calling history.pushState, window.location.pathname doesn't get changed (at least in Safari). Any way to get the changed pathname? I currently just keep track of it in a global var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try storing the current url in the stateObj

```
function toHistory(url,title) {
    history.pushState({url:url},title,url);
}
```

This works, but you have to make sure you replace the current state on first page load to update with the current url.